# iOS9 multitasking with iAd banner size

Tags: iad, ios9

I've got a universal app with an iAd banner across the bottom.  I've got it working with iOS9 multitasking.  When my app is running on the iPad in portrait and I split into 2 apps my app becomes condensed.. which works.  The iAd banner across the bottom doesn't resize to the condensed view, it's just clipped off.  Is there a way to adjust this?

Comment: I want to second your question.

Comment: Yes. I'm surprised how little chatter I can find on this. I'm also finding that displaying ads in these collapsed views doesn't format right either

Comment: Typically that means - we're doing it so wrong other people don't even think about it. Guess we stop chatting before SO will give us 10 million point down vote for chatting in comments.

Comment: Actually I started with Apple's iAd suite example project with splitview controller. I confirmed it didn't work in their example. But I need to see if that examples been updated and re-test

Comment: I did just the same. I wanted to file a report, but right now I'm not receiving any test ads at all to provide a screenshot. I really wonder how such an oversight could happen on their side.